# What does back slash following an equation mark in function argument do in Python

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, backslash

The bellow is two pieces of code (not a complete as we might not need it)
The first piece of code is the definition of a Graph class:

```
class Graph:
def __init__(self, nodes=None, edgesdict=None, heuristic=None,
             edges=None):
```

The second code is an instance of the Graph class:

```
GRAPH1 = Graph(edgesdict = \
           [{NAME:'e1',  VAL: 5, NODE1:'Common Area', NODE2:'Stairs'},
            {NAME:'e2',  VAL:15, NODE1:'Entrance Hall', NODE2:'Hospital'},
            {NAME:'e3',  VAL: 7, NODE1:'Classroom 11', NODE2:'Hospital'}
            ],
           heuristic = \
           {'Common Area':
                {'Hospital':17,
                 'Classroom 11':10}})
```

The question is: what is the `\` in `= \` for? Or why do we need to use a `\` here?

Comment: Note, in this case since you are inside a bracketed expression there is no need for the line-continuation character.

Comment: *grumbles about people ignoring [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and answering an obvious duplicate... and other people rewarding that*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is, you don't need the `\` at all (in this case**). In python, `\` is a line continuation character. All it does is make the line and the following line behave as if it were all on one line. It is only in the code for readability, and it won't cause any problems if you take it out.
**The backslash is not required here because it is a variable initialization. If you were using the backslash for something else such as continuing a string on another line, removing it will raise exceptions.

Comment: In this case taking it out won't cause any problems, but not generally.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The `\` tells python that the line of code continues to the next line.